# Как показать дочерние элементы, если родительский элемент скрыт с помощью display: none?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#liver").click(function() {
    $("#organs").hide();
    $("#part_1").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.issues_for_liver {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="organs">
  <button id="liver"> Печень </button>
</div>
<div id="issues">
  <div class="issues_for_liver">
    <!--Вопросы для установления диагноза печени-->
    <div id="part_1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_1">
      <label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так просто покажите его по клику , а не потомков ?

Comment: @splash58, мне  нужно показать  именно потомка.

Comment: Скрывай всех потомков а не родителя(например по классу). И по нужному ивенту показывай нужного потомка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел на большом SO вот этот вопрос: [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5521387/5275890), в вопросе, у автора, как и у вас указано, что родительский `div` скрыт с помощью `display:none;`. Приведу в качестве ответа два варианта решения задачи.

[Первый вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23247837/5275890), это решение, набравшее наибольшее количество голосов, решение, основывающееся не на `display:none;`, а на `visibility: hidden;`, по моему самое гуманное решение, пример:

```js
$("#liver").click(function() {
  $("#organs").hide();
  var childs = $(".parent").children();
  for (var index = 0; index < childs.length; index++) {
    childs[index].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
});
```

```css
.parent>.child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.parent {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="organs">
  <button id="liver"> Печень </button>
</div>

<div id="issues">
  <div class="parent">
    <div id="part_1" class="child">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_1">
      <label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Второй вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5521420/5275890), это решение, принятое как верное, основывающееся на `display:none;`, но идея в другом. С автором я согласен, он пишет: *Я не думаю, что это возможно. Вы можете использовать `JavaScript`, чтобы вытащить элемент из скрытого элемента, дублировать его, а затем добавить его к любому элементу, который видим.* Пример решения:

```js
$("#liver").click(function() {
  $("#organs").hide();
  var element = $('#part_1').clone();
  $('#part_1').remove();
  element.appendTo($('#issues'));
});
```

```css
.issues_for_liver {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="organs">
  <button id="liver"> Печень </button>
</div>

<div id="issues">
  <div class="issues_for_liver">
    <div id="part_1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="liver_1">
      <label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Решение не самое красивое, но оно отмечено как принятое, я добавил одну строку `$('#part_1').remove();` для удаления элемента, который клонировали.

Если элемент `display: none;`, то дочерние элементы отобразить не получится. Предлагаю выбрать в качестве решения первый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Примените `display: none` к детям. Если дети не отображаются, то родитель отображаться тоже не будет, его можно вообще не скрывать. Или отображайте родителя вместе с детьми.

Comment: Кто минусовал, поясните, за что.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, минусовал не я, но объяснить могу: текст плохо форматирован, в нем ошибки, смысл лично мне удалось уловить только с третьего прочтения + желательно такое простое описание проиллюстрировать кодом, чтобы после пары раз неудачных прочтений, хотя бы код можно было попытаться понять. А так кто-то прочитал по диагонали, ничего не понял — минус.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Спасибо за ответ. Полностью согласен с вашей критикой. По-моему, здесь нужен как раз комментарий, подобный вашему, а не минус. Уж точно - не минус без пояснений.